# typescript HTML datatype as class parameter

Tags: angular, typescript

Sorry if this is a common question.

I am currently creating my portfolio in an angular app, and it would be nice if each project in my portfolio could have some custom HTML inside it.

```
export class Item {
    constructor(public name:string, public description:string, public imagePath:string){}
}
```

is there some kind of HTML type that i could use instead of string for the description?

Comment: Yes but probably you only know what the type would be. Looking at your code they all look like they could be a string to me.

Comment: Since you don't actually hold HTML components but the string representing them `string` is most fitting

Comment: But what if i wanted each "Item" in my portfolio to hold a variable number of images and paragraphs like this:

    item: Item 0 = new Item(
    'project1',
    '<h1>Hello</h1>
    <a>link1</a> 
    <a>link2</a>
    ',
    ''
    )

Comment: make an array of strings?

Comment: I dont want an array with ['hello','link1','link2'].
i want something to output the whole HTML code written above.

Comment: there are types for the dom nodes included in the standard library.. but they'll just all be HTMLElement and you have to create them by hand using document.createElement anyway.. in your case is easier to just set the innerHTML property of an element to the string you want.. it's ugly but it works..

Comment: All right. Thank you for your help!